# Can ESP32 BLE be server and client at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm trying to make smart social distancing circuit for COVID 19. I plan on using ESP32 for this. But it would be good if ESP BLE could be client and scan for other Bluetooth devices at the same time.

Could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically trying to understand if the Bluetooth Low Energy software stack that comes with ESP32 supports the "dual role" feature.

1. Try Googling "dual role ble esp32"
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/esp32/comments/ebc8lj/how_to_use_dual_role_bluetooth_le/
3. https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=1027 (*)

(*) The post is 4 years old. Something might have changed now.